# Agrupamiento en columnas y filas de elementos

Tags: html, css

hace unos días estoy buscando como hacer esto pero no lo he logrado... resulta que tengo un código que la idea es que muestre múltiples banderas de idioma, solo puedo poner 3 en una fila de esta manera

```
españa
UK
francia
portugal
Argentina
```

Pero necesito que sea algo así

```
españa    portugal
UK        Argentina
francia
```

Está hecho en css y html, los codigos son estos.

```css
    header .panel{position:absolute;right:16px;height:100%;top:0;}
    header .panel .lang{width:30px;position:absolute;right:0;height:100%;padding:4px 0;}
    header .panel .lang li{width:30px;height:33.33%;border-right:0;}
    header .panel .lang li a{opacity:.5;width:100%;height:100%;padding-top:1px;}
    header .panel .lang li a:hover{background:none;opacity:1;}
    header .panel .lang li.active a{opacity:1;}
    header .panel .link{cursor:pointer;width:calc(50% - 15px);font-size:20px;display:inline-block;border-right:1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.15);}
    header .panel .link.menu{display:none;}
    header .panel .link div{top:-2px;left:1px;}
```

```html
<ul class="lang">
    <li class="active"><a><img src="/template/img/langs/es.png"/></a></li>
    <li><a><img src="/template/img/langs/en.png"/></a></li>
    <li><a><img src="/template/img/langs/fr.png"/></a></li>
    <li><a><img src="/template/img/langs/pt.png"/></a></li>
    <li><a><img src="/template/img/langs/ar.png"/></a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

- Si necesitas que se acomoden en 2 columnas y que en la primera queden 3 banderas y en la segunda solamente dos
- Te puedes apoyar de grid para realizar lo siguiente:

  - El contenedor que sería tu etiqueta **`ul`** agrégale un **`display: grid;`**
  - La distribución de las columnas y renglones se hará de esta forma: 2 columnas con un ancho de **`1fr`** a través de la propiedad **`grid-template-columns`** en la etiqueta contenedor que será el **`ul`**

```html
    <style>
      .banderas-paises {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
      }
      .banderas-paises__pais {
        border: solid 1px;
        list-style: none;
      }
    </style>
    <ul class="banderas-paises">
      <li class="banderas-paises__pais">España</li>
      <li class="banderas-paises__pais">UK</li>
      <li class="banderas-paises__pais">Francia</li>
      <li class="banderas-paises__pais">Portugal</li>
      <li class="banderas-paises__pais">Argentina</li>
    </ul>
```

Con un resultado como este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]